# Change placeholders in Subject

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a template where I can have VBA prompt me to change items in the subject. I've a template email with the subject line that should be Project / GC/Client, and in the template I've written that as #0# / #1#.

I'm at the below, but it's erroring.

```
Private Sub m_Inspector_Activate()

    Dim Item As MailItem
    Dim Value As String
    If TypeOf m_Inspector.CurrentItem Is MailItem Then
        Set mail = m_Inspector.CurrentItem
        If mail.Subject = "subject" Then
            Value = InputBox("Project")
            mail.Subject = Replace(mail.Subject, "#0#", Value)

            Value = InputBox("GC/Client")
            mail.Subject = Replace(mail.Subject, "#1#", Value)
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

This code is used on a template button in Outlook. i.e. the template file it is launching contains the subject line of #0# / #1#. Ideally, after the template launches, the macro prompts the user to update those two fields with the proper subjects.

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate _
      ("V:\All Folders\Templates\Freebie.oft")
    MyItem.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the error? also, can you explain the use of the pound sign in `"#0#"`

Comment: It's a 424 saying it doesn't see an object in line 4.  I used pound signs around numbers as they're unlikely to actually be used in an e-mail subject line, and thus only the template that uses them will be corrected when this runs.

Comment: have you included the other necessary code to ensure that this is loaded on startup? http://www.vboffice.net/en/developers/newinspector-and-inspector-activate/

Comment: for example, in the snippet we see here you do not include a declaration for `m_Inspector`

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that guidance.  I added that code, but now it's calling the first line's m_Inspector_Activate () and ambiguous name.

Comment: I appreciate your help.  I'm rather new to using this functionality, and I'm trying to understand the activation code.

Comment: actually now that i've posted an answer i realize that the `Replace(...)` wont work the way that it is currently implemented. The if statement checks to see if the whole string of the subject is "subject". When that is true, "#0#" will not be in the subject. Can you clarify what you want to accomplish with the Replace?

Comment: "subject" was a place holder so I wouldn't confuse others with #0# / #1# in the subject, but that's what's in my actual code.  I tried what's below, but when I put it in the same module as the template launch, it breaks the whole package.  That code is:

Comment: Sub CommandButton1_Click()
     Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate _
     ("V:\All Folders\Templates\Freebie.oft")
     MyItem.Display
    End Sub

Comment: So I'm not sure anymore when exactly you want this macro to activate? I don't see how the code above relates to the question

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; the code above is used on a template button in Outlook.  i.e. the template file it is launching contains the subject line of #0# / #1#.  Ideally, after the template launches, the macro we're working on then prompts the user to update those two fields with the proper subjects.  Does that make sense?  That's why I'm trying to combine all of this into one module.

Comment: Oh, then let me try a different and hopefully simpler approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all that you really want to do is open a template and replace text in the subject line, this may work for you:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call OpenTemplate
End Sub

Sub OpenTemplate()

    Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OutMail = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("V:\All Folders\Templates\Freebie.oft")

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""

        .Subject = Replace(.Subject, "#0#", InputBox("Project"))
        .Subject = Replace(.Subject, "#1#", InputBox("GC/Client"))

        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

If we can avoid using the Inspector then this is much simpler

Comment: This is a perfect, and elegant, solution!  Thanks for sending me down a more simple path!

Comment: Question for you: if I try to apply the same logic of this formula to the body of the template, it removes the HTML formatting, which is required to keep the data in a table format.  Any ideas on how to make this compatible?

Comment: @ChrisJay hmm nope I don't have experience with that, you ought to open another question for it :)